# Cleaner/better way to add props to a styled JSS object/component [Material UI, React, JSS]

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui, jss, css-in-js

Is there a "cleaner" way to add props to a `styled()` object in Material UI? IMO the formatting/syntax is not very elegant especially with typescript. The Material UI docs gives the following [example](https://material-ui.com/styles/basics/#adapting-the-styled-components-api) for adding props:

(Javascript)

```
const MyButton = styled(({ color, ...other }) => <Button {...other} />)({
  background: (props) =>
    props.color === 'red'
      ? 'linear-gradient(45deg, #FE6B8B 30%, #FF8E53 90%)'
      : 'linear-gradient(45deg, #2196F3 30%, #21CBF3 90%)',
  border: 0,
  borderRadius: 3,
  boxShadow: (props) =>
    props.color === 'red'
      ? '0 3px 5px 2px rgba(255, 105, 135, .3)'
      : '0 3px 5px 2px rgba(33, 203, 243, .3)',
  color: 'white',
  height: 48,
  padding: '0 30px',
  margin: 8,
});
```

(Typescript)

```
interface MyButtonProps {
  color: 'red' | 'blue';
}

const MyButton = styled(
  ({ color, ...other }: MyButtonProps & Omit<ButtonProps, keyof MyButtonProps>) => (
    <Button {...other} />
  ),
)({
  background: (props: MyButtonProps) =>
    props.color === 'red'
      ? 'linear-gradient(45deg, #FE6B8B 30%, #FF8E53 90%)'
      : 'linear-gradient(45deg, #2196F3 30%, #21CBF3 90%)',
  border: 0,
  borderRadius: 3,
  boxShadow: (props: MyButtonProps) =>
    props.color === 'red'
      ? '0 3px 5px 2px rgba(255, 105, 135, .3)'
      : '0 3px 5px 2px rgba(33, 203, 243, .3)',
  color: 'white',
  height: 48,
  padding: '0 30px',
  margin: 8,
});
```

Is there a way to write it like:

(Typescript)

```
const MyButton = styled(
  (props: {
    color: string,
  }) => (
    <div />
  ),
)(props => ({
  background: props.color === 'red' ? 'linear-gradient(45deg, #FE6B8B 30%, #FF8E53 90%)' : 'linear-gradient(45deg, #2196F3 30%, #21CBF3 90%)',
  border: 0,
  borderRadius: 3,
  boxShadow: props.color === 'red' ? '0 3px 5px 2px rgba(255, 105, 135, .3)' : '0 3px 5px 2px rgba(33, 203, 243, .3)',
  color: 'white',
  height: 48,
  padding: '0 30px',
  margin: 8,
}));
```

The "proposed syntax" that I'm giving doesn't reuse the MyButtonProps interface multiple times and the props object is passed into the whole object (similar to the way a "theme" object would get passed in).

Comment: The `props => ({` syntax in your proposal is actually supported already!  The idea of declaring dropped props and/or required props is interesting.  It can probably be done by creating a custom wrapper around the `styled` HOC.  If certain props are going to not be passed through, like `color`, that property name has to exist in the JS and not just in the TS.

Comment: @LindaPaiste Your right, passing in props works. I guess it's possible to create a wrapper/custom version of the `styled` HOC, but it would be better to just use something that comes with the package IMO. Thanks for the reply and suggestion